# FireMonkey tRectangle with tLabel child

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am coding a custom control based on `tRectangle`:

```
tMyRect = class (tRectangle)
```

On the `tMyRect Constructor`, I create a `tLabel`:

```
fRectLabel := tLabel.Create (Self);
```

and then set some properties for it.

At runtime, the `tLabel` is not showed according to the properties settings, neither responds to the speedkey.

Follows the complete code:

```
unit frmMyRect;
interface
uses FMX.Controls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Forms, FMX.Layouts, 
     FMX.Objects, FMXFMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Types,System.Classes, System.UITypes;
type
  tfrmMyRect =  class (tForm)
     procedure FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
  end;
  tMyRect = class (tRectangle)
    fRectLabel : tLabel;
    constructor Create (aOwner: tComponent);
  end;
var formMyRect: tfrmMyRect;
implementation
{$R *.fmx}
var MyRect : tMyRect;
procedure tformMyRect.FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
begin
   MyRect := tMyRect.Create (Self);
   MyRect.Parent := frmMyRect;
end; { FormCreate }
constructor tMyRect.Create (aOwner: tComponent);
begin
   inherited;
  Align      := tAlignLayout.Center;
  CanFocus   :=  True;
  Height     :=   23;
  Width      :=   80;
  fRectLabel := tLabel.Create (Self);
    with fRectLabel do begin
           Align        := tAlignLayout.Center;
           AutoSize     :=  True;
           FocusControl :=  Self;
           HitTest      :=  True;
           Parent       :=  Self;
           Text         := 'Labe&l';
            with TextSettings do begin
                 FontColor  := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
                 WordWrap   :=  False;
                 Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
            end;
    end;
  end; { Create }
end.
```

I appreciate if someone can clarify why the `tLabel` does not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the StyleSettings property of the TLabel so that the styling system does not apply those that you have changed, e.g.:

```
  StyledSettings := StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor, TStyledSetting.Style];
```

As to the "neither responds to the speedkey" part, you'll need to clarify what you mean, as you have not shown code related to that

Comment: When I set, the FocusControl := Self; HitTest := True; Text := 'Labe&l'; of fRectLabel properties, I expect that at runtime, the Alt + l key combination, will cause MyRect to be the active control, and consequently got the focus.This is the response that is not triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer about the StyledSettings. I didn't realize that by default that property is set to [Family, Size], although if I drop a tLabel in a form, the TextSettings will take precedence over the StyledSettings. I can not understand why it does not behave the same way when I create the tLabel at runtime. Also IMHO, the compiler should not assume that the control is styled, since this is tricky for programmers like me, that used to code in the VCL environment. I spent many hours trying to figure out why the code didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any tip regarding the `speedkey` issue? Thanks.

Comment: @user2383818 When you set the Text property of the TLabel, the speedkey implementation is expecting the label to be (ultimately) parented to the form. Since its parent (the TMyRect) is not parented to anything yet, the speedkey is not registered. You would need to set (or update) the Text property of the TLabel *after* the TMyRect's Parent has been set