# Firemonkey accelerator key

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, acceleratorkey, tlabel

I'm looking for a way to register the `accelerator key` other than the standard way, that is when the text with the `accelerator key` is set to the `tLabel`.

I googled a lot and did not find nothing of the sort.

Also, in other question, was suggested to set the `Label's` Text property at `Form's` creation, after setting the `Label's` parent, but this does not work because the `Label's` Text and Parent properties, might be set dynamically at run time.

Assuming the form has a `TEdit`, a `TLabel` and a `TRectangle`, named respectively `MyEdit`, `MyLabel` and `MyRect`, follows a brief code example

```
...
interface
type
tMyForm = class (TForm)
...
 procedure FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
...
end;
...
implementation
tMyForm.FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
begin
  ...
  MyLabel.FocusControl := MyEdit;
  MyLabel.Text := '&Label';
  MyLabel.Parent := MyRect; // after this setting
                            //   the accelerator key stop working
// I need some code here that makes the accelerator key work, no matter where 
// I set the TLabel's Text and Parent properties
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]

Comment: @Tom Burning. Well, I expect that when pressing `Alt + accel key` (any valid accel key btw), the control assigned to the label's `FocusControl` property should get the focus. Is that asking too much?

Comment: In XE7, which I'm working with now, there is no such thing as (FMX) TLabel.FocusControl. Which raises the question,  *which version are you using?* **Edit:** Looking at documentation for `Rio` I see that a (FMX) `TLabel.FocusControl` exists. Sorry, I can not help you further as I'm on XE7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FireMonkey tRectangle with tLabel child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827205/firemonkey-trectangle-with-tlabel-child)

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. I appreciate your help. Thanks anyway!